# Preprocessor directive to simulate a notation

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

In C++, is there a methodology by means of the preprocessor to substitute for a variable name followed by an index number by: its name followed by '[' followed by the index number, followed by ']'?

As an example, if I write:

```
int main(void)
{
    int var[64];
    var0 = 0;
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 2; // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Translation:

```
int main(void)
{
    int var[64];
    var[0] = 0;
    var[1] = 1;
    var[2] = 2; // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this rather than just writing correct, syntactically valid C++ from the outset?

Comment: So you want to have multiple  separate objects but you want to treat them like they are a array?

Comment: @JesperJuhl because I want to use an array instead of declared variables in a specific project, and I don't want to mess up

Comment: Seems to me that you are just as likely to mess up with an ugly macro (possibly in surprising ways) than just writing the correct code in the first place...

Comment: If you want to use an array, go ahead and use it. What is there to mess up with `[]` that you can't mess up without `[]`?

Comment: Put your code in a version control system and refactor it. If you mess things, just revert to a previous valid version

Comment: @Amadeus +1 - so obvious it shouldn't be needed to mention it, but yeah..

Comment: @JesperJuhl He is afraid of messing things up. Really very obvious, but this is one of his main concerns, and probably, one of the solution, if not the best :P

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is going to be the closest you can get.

```
#define var0 var[0]
#define var1 var[1]
...
```

However, it should be noted if you're going to use the above, you may as well just do it manually in the first place, since you're typing everything out anyway.

Comment: Not to mention that you'll weird out all your future coworkers who'll work on the code in the future.. hacks like this should be actively discouraged since it creates a dialect language and makes the code harder (surprising) to read.

Answer (score 0):

No. Thanks to language creators! There is no way to make syntax analysis (string parsing) inside macro definition.
It would be the real hell to read such programs.

Comment: If you pass some parameters to a `function` it must be obvious. That's why I hate `C#` `dynamic`.